# Shopify - Date Selection issue

Tags: jquery, shopify, jquery-ui-datepicker, cart

I am having issue with date selection in shopify.
I am creating a theme for client. But I have no clue what's wrong with this datepicker.
https://chicken-rice.myshopify.com/cart
password: bbq

You'll have to add a product first
https://chicken-rice.myshopify.com/products/product-a
then go to cart and click the datepicker at step 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you check console, you will see that there are many javascript errors. Also your datepicker is throwing an error, as below:-

[image]

You will have to resolve these for making datepicker work.